# Wpf adding more views to tabcontrol dynamically with prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I looking for a hint or just a direction how to design the structure I need because its a little tricky. I am using MVVM and Prism.

I have 2 regions, one with 2 buttons and one tabcontrol region. After clicking on button1 I want to inject 3 views as tabs into the tabcontrol. After clicking on button2 I want to remove the tabs from button1 (but keep the data behind) and inject again 3 views as tabs in the tabcontrol. And here comes the tricky part :-), this should happen dynamically and 2 of the 3 views from button1 and button2 are based on the same view/viewmodel.

I am thankfull for everything I can get :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the ViewModel first approach. Here is a quick and dirty way to do this, clean it up at your own convenience.

**View/ViewModel structure:**

View1 - ViewModel1 : IViewModel

View2 - ViewModel2 : IViewModel

View3 - ViewModel3 : IViewModel

IViewModel requires a "Content" string property

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SFQ1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SFQ1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
            <local:View1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
            <local:View2/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel3}">
            <local:View3/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding VmObservable}">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" Content="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding SetOneCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Margin="130,0,0,0" Width="100" Content="2" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding SetTwoCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly List<IViewModel> _viewModelCollection;

    private ObservableCollection<IViewModel> _vmObservable;
    public ObservableCollection<IViewModel> VmObservable
    {
        get { return _vmObservable; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _vmObservable, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private IViewModel _activeVm;
    public IViewModel ActiveVm
    {
        get { return _activeVm; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _activeVm, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand SetOneCommand { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand SetTwoCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SetOneCommand = new DelegateCommand(SetOne);
        SetTwoCommand = new DelegateCommand(SetTwo);
        VmObservable = new ObservableCollection<IViewModel>();

        _viewModelCollection = new List<IViewModel>()
        {
            new ViewModel1(),
            new ViewModel2(),
            new ViewModel3()
        };
    }

    private void SetOne()
    {
        VmObservable.Clear();
        VmObservable.Add(GetViewModel(typeof(ViewModel1)));
        VmObservable.Add(GetViewModel(typeof(ViewModel2)));
        VmObservable.Add(GetViewModel(typeof(ViewModel3)));
    }

    private void SetTwo()
    {
        VmObservable.Clear();
        VmObservable.Add(GetViewModel(typeof(ViewModel2)));
        VmObservable.Add(GetViewModel(typeof(ViewModel3)));
    }

    private IViewModel GetViewModel( Type viewModelType )
    {
        return _viewModelCollection.Find(x => x.GetType().Equals(viewModelType));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer and time. This put me in the right direction. I was way of track... With a few modifications it should work as I need it :-)